# alternative to check, whether a value is in a set

Tags: delphi, set

I have the following code. It looks ugly, if the value equals to one of the following value then do something.

```
var
  Value: Word;
begin
  Value := 30000;
  if (Value = 30000) or (Value = 40000) or (Value = 1) then
    do_something;
end;
```

I want to refactor the code as follows:

```
var
  Value: Word;
begin
  Value := 30000;
  if (Value in [1, 30000, 40000]) then // Does not work
    do_something;
end;
```

However, the refactored code does not work. I assume that a valid set in Delphi accepts only elements with type byte. If there any good alternative to refactor my original code (besides using case)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think something like this?

```
case value of
  1, 30000, 40000: do_somthing
end;
```

Comment: thanks, but as I have noted in my question, I want another alternative. Because using switch...case for such a logic looks not normal

Comment: @stanleyxu2005. It's probably the most efficient. And, besides, when you start writing thing like this, there is a good chance that you might end up having to add an else or even an else if condition `if value in [.] do bla else if value in [..] do blabla else do blablabla`.  In such a case, the case is the obvious choice.

Comment: After one day waiting for responses, I agree that using switch...case is the most acceptable solution.

Comment: I completely read over that last part of your question, though I still think a case would be the best solution here, so I'm glad we agree. :-) Even though I also like TOndrej's answer.

Answer (score 14):

How about using an open array?

```
function ValueIn(Value: Integer; const Values: array of Integer): Boolean;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  for I := Low(Values) to High(Values) do
    if Value = Values[I] then
    begin
      Result := True;
      Break;
    end;
end;
```

Example (pseudo-code):

```
var
  Value: Integer;
begin
  Value := ...;
  if ValueIn(Value, [30000, 40000, 1]) then
    ...
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a class for larger bitsets, see Classes.TBits.

While it won't do constant expressions easily, it can be useful in certain other cases.